# ORA-31011: XML parsing failed

Tags: xml, oracle

```
select xmltype(clob_content) from table
```

error

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 - "XML parsing failed"
*Cause: XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action: Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

Here is my XML:

[image]

Comment: Most likely the content you have in that column is not a valid XML document. Please [edit] your question to include the XML content you have in that `clob_content` column.

Comment: Do not add any code as images to your question, add the code to the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data you posted is OK:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '
  3      <company>
  4        <employee>
  5          <empno>7839></empno>
  6          <ename>king</ename>
  7          <hiredate>1981-11-17</hiredate>
  8          <sal>5000</sal>
  9          <deptno>10</deptno>
 10          <dname>accounting</dname>
 11        </employee>
 12      </company>'
 13     from dual
 14    )
 15  select xmltype(col) From test;

XMLTYPE(COL)
--------------------------------------------------------
<company>
  <employee>
    <empno>7839&gt;</empno>
    <ename>king</ename>
    <hiredate>1981-11-17</hiredate>
    <sal>5000</sal>
    <deptno>10</deptno>
    <dname>accounting</dname>
  </employee>
</company>


SQL>
```

but that's probably not the case with the rest of rows in the table. For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '
  3      <company>
  4        <employee>
  5          <empno>7839></empno>
  6          <ename>king<ename>                --> wrong closing tag
  7          <hiredate>1981-11-17</hiredate>
  8          <sal>5000</sal>
  9          <deptno>10</deptno>
 10          <dname>accounting</dname>
 11        </employee>
 12      </company>'
 13     from dual
 14    )
 15  select xmltype(col) From test;
ERROR:
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00225: end-element tag "employee" does not match start-element tag "ename"
Error at line 10
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 1



no rows selected

SQL>
```

How to find a culprit? A simple (and probably not very efficient) approach is to loop through the table and apply `XMLTYPE` to every row, separately. Once you hit the error, display the contents and examine what's wrong with it.

Comment: thanks for your answer,
actually XMLTYPE support file till 4gb how we process the file if file limit increase 4gb?

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry. **Do you** have that large files, or are you just being curious?

Comment: actually i curious because its telecom data